# Extract a character from a filename +1 character

Tags: r, regex

I want to be able to extract a character from a filename. I want to extract B+1 character

```
df <- c("2010-01-14_B1_RP_NEG_09.mzML","2010-01-14_B1_RP_NEG_10.mzML","2010-01-15_B2_RP_NEG_11.mzML","2010-01-15_B2_RP_NEG_12.mzML", "2010-01-16_B3_RP_NEG_13.mzML", "2010-01-16_B3_RP_NEG_14.mzML")
df
```

It could be done by:

```
substring(df,12,13)
```

But in a long filename it would eb convenient to know how to extract B+1 character. This code extract the characters after B.

```
substring(df, regexpr("B", df)+1)
```

It should look like

```
B1, B1, B2, B2, B3, B3
```

Any good suggestions?:)

Comment: A another option: `regmatches(x, regexpr("B\\d{1}", x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sub` we can extract "B" followed by a number.

```
sub(".*(B\\d+).*", "\\1", df)
#[1] "B1" "B1" "B2" "B2" "B3" "B3"
```

Or with `str_extract` :

```
stringr::str_extract(df, "B\\d+")
```

Comment: I think you should get rid of the `+` in your regular expression, as only one digit after the B is required

Comment: Probably, yes. But sometimes the number goes beyond 9 and then it fails. In this case, it doesn't matter though.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `substr` with `trimws` in `base R`

```
substr(trimws(df, whitespace = '^[^_]+_'), 1, 2)
#[1] "B1" "B1" "B2" "B2" "B3" "B3"
```